# Footer not fully flush and background images not repeating y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a gap from the bottom of the page and the footer which i cant figure out how to fix, also my background left and right images wont repeat on its y-axis.
Can anybody help with why this is happening? appreciate the help! :)
Thanks!
*Edit* Ive put it to repeat on the x axis on the code by accident but it doesnt repeat on the y axis still, this is really confusing!

```js
/*----------Menu Sticky Script Start----------*/
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 128){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
/*----------Menu Sticky Script Start----------*/
/*----------Menu Sticky Script Start----------*/
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
}
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
var dir = 1;
var MIN_TOP = 200;
var MAX_TOP = 350;
function autoscroll() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop() + dir;
    if (window_top >= MAX_TOP) {
        window_top = MAX_TOP;
        dir = -1;
    } else if (window_top <= MIN_TOP) {
        window_top = MIN_TOP;
        dir = 1;
    }
    $(window).scrollTop(window_top);
    window.setTimeout(autoscroll, 100);
}
/*----------Menu Sticky Script End----------*/
/*----------Sidebar Right Sticky Script Start----------*/
        $(function() {
            var offset = $("#sidebar-right").offset();
            var topPadding = 140;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $("#sidebar-right").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar-right").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
/*----------Sidebar Right Sticky Script End----------*/
/*----------Sidebar Left Sticky Script Start----------*/
        $(function() {
            var offset = $("#sidebar-left").offset();
            var topPadding = 140;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $("#sidebar-left").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar-left").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
/*----------Sidebar Left Sticky Script End----------*/
/*----------Footer Script Start----------*/
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
       var footerHeight = $('.footer').outerHeight();
       var stickFooterPush = $('.push').height(footerHeight);
  
       $('.wrapper').css({'marginBottom':'-' + footerHeight + 'px'});
      });
  
      $(window).resize();
     });
/*----------Footer Script End----------*/
```

```css
/*--------------------
Website Styling Start
--------------------*/
* {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 background-color:red;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: white;
 }
html {position: relative;min-height: 100%;}
body {
 background-image: url(../../images/background/backgroundleft.jpg), url(../../images/background/backgroundright.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: top left, top right;
}
.page-wrap{margin: 0 auto; width : 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;


}
/*--------------------
Website Styling End
--------------------*/
/*----------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------
Content Styling Start
--------------------*/
#banner{
 background-color: #7B007A;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 40px 0;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}
header{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 80px;
 height: 120px;
 background: #335C7D;
 color: #fff;
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 }
header.sticky {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
   height: 80px;
   background: #8A492C;
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: 20px;
}
#content{float:left;width:70%;background-color: white; color: black; }
#sidebar-right{float:right;width:15%; background-color: #565656; display: inline-block;}
#sidebar-left{float:left;width:15%; background-color: #565656;}


footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
 

} 
#footertop {
 height: 20%;
 background-color: #346725;
}
#footerbottom {
 height: 80%;
 background-color: #363636;
}

 /*---
 /*--------------------
Content Styling End
--------------------*/
/*----------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------
Scripting Styling Start
--------------------*/


#sticky {
 width: 100%;
}

#sticky.stick {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}

/*--------------------
Scripting Styling End
--------------------*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--HTML Start-->
<!--------------------------->
<div id="banner">
<p>Banner</p>
</div>
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">
<header><h1>Sticky Header</h1></header>
</div>
<div class="page-wrap">
<div id="sidebar-right">
    <p>Sticky Sidebar</p>
    <p>Sticky Sidebar</p>
    <p>Sticky Sidebar</p>
    <p>Sticky Sidebar</p>
</div>
<div id="sidebar-left">
    <p>Sticky Sidebar</p>
    <p>Sticky Sidebar</p>
    <p>Sticky Sidebar</p>
    <p>Sticky Sidebar</p>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
    <p>Filler filler filler......</p>
</div>

</div>

<footer class="footer">
<div id="footertop">
</div>
<div id="footerbottom">
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: are you talking about the red line at the end

Comment: Yes, i made the background color on the body red so you can see that there is a gap, this is the best ive managed to get with internet explorer working

Comment: @LawrenceWilliamTrigg Try `display:table;` for `.footer` class.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked brilliantly! :) ive been searching for ages trying to figure this out! Im not sure how to tick your answer as being correct though?
Any idea about my multiple background image not being repeated by its Y Axis? im sure that my code is correct?